# Questions have vertical misalignments

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

"Random" vertical gaps appear in questions. They don't seem to be justified by the context.

The overall effect is that a question with 3 lines of copy has huge amounts of white space, a lot of space for comments and a notice (like a "closed" notice) *very far away* from the post it belongs to.

See for example this comparison with StackOverflow. No major white space, font and colours are used to maximize the visibility of the elements and to minimise the wasted space.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

As addressed earlier the extra space in comments is for the flag.

The gap under and above comments is matching.

Add/show comments was vetoed as having a bg color or any button like / decorative nature - but it does have equal spacing or your "2 line gap"

The notices appear underneath of comments in all examples I see.
This is network-wide.

The main top space you are heralding as "This should not be here....etc" is not accounting for the signature blocks of owner and/or editors or the voting/social tools on the left.

This also seems to be the case in all of the examples and other sites I've seen.

Comment: Sean, I'll post an image from SO - without the gaps.

Comment: The space around the "Add more comments" is significantly larger than on other SE sites, see my [direct comparison in this answer](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/1569/5). If you put those two pictures from my answer side-by-side, the Skeptics theme takes up significantly more space vertically.

Comment: decreased space around .comments-link for you

Comment: erm, not fixed yet, still full of gaps here, around "add a comment" etc.

Comment: we push builds out on tuesdays and wednesdays. this is fixed on the dev servers.